# Using ~> and <~ several times in Scala parser combinator library

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I'm using scala parser combinator library to parse terms belonging to a term-rewriter library. Here is the code that is giving me problems:

```
def parser: Parser[(Map[String,Operation],List[Rule])] =
    "section signature\n" ~> signature <~ "end signature" ~
      "section rules\n" ~> rules <~ "end rules" ^^ {
      case s ~ rs => (s,rs)
    }
```

The intention is to pattern match onlythe signature and rules in the partial function. However, the above code gives a compile error and the best I can do is:

```
def parser: Parser[(Map[String,Operation],List[Rule])] =
    "section signature\n" ~> signature ~ "end signature" ~
      "section rules\n" ~ rules <~ "end rules" ^^ {
      case s ~ "end signature" ~ "section rules\n" ~ rs => (s,rs)
    }
```

Is there a way to get rid of "end signature" ~ "section rules\n" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd usually do something like this:

```
("section signature\n" ~> signature <~ "end signature") ~
("section rules\n" ~> rules <~ "end rules")
```

By the way: the explicit `\n` looks suspicious. Is it really needed? Likewise, the hard-coded spaces also look strange. What if the input contains `"section  signature"` or `"section\n  signature"`? What if a line ends with a space (nasty, because invisible without special text editor settings)? Does the parser really have to fail catastrophically on every minor variation of the whitespace?

Comment: @Rodrigo I've updated the answer slightly. Not only is `\n` not needed: probably all the whitespace characters shouldn't be there in the first place. In particular, `\n` would break on every input where the line contains spaces in the end, before the line break.